# Problems getting an image to upload to db with laravel

Tags: php, symfony, laravel-4

So I want to upload and image and my view looks like this:

```
<form action="" class="dropzone" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="my-awesome-   
dropzone">
       <div class="default message">
            <div class="col-lg-1">
                <input type="file" id="image" class="file-pos" name="image">
                <br />
                <button class="btn btn-theme" name="upload" type="submit">Upload your 
                portfolio</button>
            </div>
        </div>  
</form>
```

And my code in my controller looks like this:

```
public function uploadPortfolio()
{
        $userid = Auth::user()->id;
        $image = new Image();
        $image = Input::file('image');
        $file_name = Input::file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
        $upload_folder = '/assets/uploads/portfolio/';
        $image->move(public_path() . $upload_folder, $file_name);
        $image->save(array('image' => $file_name));
        return Redirect::to('/users/uploadPortfolio');
}
```

The error I get is: `Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException`
which as I understand is a problem with my routing but even if I put the return in comment I still get this error. Anybody got an idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Show us your routes file

Comment: Edit your question and place your routes there

Comment: you were right i forgot to place my routes code which is  Route::post('/users/uploadPortfolio', 'UserController@uploadPortfolio'); But the problem is not solved now i face another error. i will try to google it first and see if i can find a solution otherwise i will return to stack overflow. thanks any way for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: @GY22 Why do you use HTML input tags when Laravel provides rich set of HTML and FORM class?